# How do I change the label of a Grand Total in Tableau Server

Tags: tableau

I have a simple grid with many columns and rows, with numeric data.  I added a grand total row at the bottom by going to Analysis -> Totals -> Show Column Grand Totals.

The label for this row is "Grand Total", and I want to change this label.  How do I do it?  Note, when I right click directly on "Grand Total", there is no "Format" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server version has limited formatting options.
You can do that in Desktop only, where totals formatting is available (https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/renaming-grand-total-header).